# ext.js self maintained store

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller

What is the shortest quickest way to get a client side store, that uses some kind of a callback / listener to return data (not from a server). Explained:

```
Ext.define('aaa.store.ContactList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'aaa.model.ContactList',
    model: 'aaa.model.ContactList',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields:['firstLetter', 'userId', 'userName', 'h', 'w', 'm', 'v', 'custom'],
    groupField: 'firstLetter',
    sorters: ['firstLetter', 'userId'],

    // Overriding the model's default proxy
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        directFn: 'getPhoneBookEntries', <<--- don't want this to be a server method, but a client side js method...
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ''
        }
    }
});
```

I got a grid using this store to show a contact list. The problem is both 'direct' and other methods rely on the fact that the store reads from a server. but I have my mechanism to read from the server, and I just want to 'feed' the store manually.

Can this be done?

Updating question with some **new** code:

**Model:**

```
Ext.define('WebPhone.model.ContactList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'firstLetter', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'userId', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'userName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'h', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'w', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'm', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'v', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'custom', type: 'string' }

    ]
});
```

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('WebPhone.store.ContactList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'WebPhone.model.ContactList',
    model: 'WebPhone.model.ContactList',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields:['firstLetter', 'userId', 'userName', 'h', 'w', 'm', 'v', 'custom'],
    groupField: 'firstLetter',
    sorters: ['firstLetter', 'userId'],

    // Overriding the model's default proxy
//    proxy: {
//        type: 'memory',
//        reader: {
//            type: 'json',
//            rootProperty: 'root'
//        }
//    }
});
```

**The gride definition is too long for this post, but it worked with pre-loaded data**

**Data loading code:**

```
var store = Ext.getStore( "ContactList" );
//var array_values = new Array();
//for( var key in phoneBook )
    //array_values.push( phoneBook[key] );
//store.loadData( array_values );
store.loadData( [{firstLetter:'a', userId:'ali', userName:'ali', h:'04040', w:'04040', m:'04040', v:'04040', custom:'04040'}] );
```

I tried both loadRawData and loadData without success ...
Tried with a proxy (ajax/json/memory/array... you name it) and without.

No success. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to configure the store without proxy and once you have your data ready call:

[`store.loadData(yourData)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData)

Comment: must it be done manually? or should I load the data in the grid's onRender listener?

Comment: store.loadData is the right solution to load data from javascript.
Use grid.getView().refresh(); to refresh grid

Comment: I manage to loadData() and getview().refresh() ... yet the view doesn't seem to refresh itself. It's still empty. Shoudl I populate the store/model with some data upon start?

Comment: You don't need to manually refresh the view, `loadData` will do it. Chances are you have some other bug in your code. Make a fiddle: http://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: Probably a bug... but how to find it??

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fixed the issue...

1. The store should be retrieved from the grid view
2. loadData() did not work for some reason. loadRawData did. Why? don't know.

Anyway.. Code:

```
var contactListView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('contact-list-view')[0];
var store = contactListView.getStore();
var array_values = new Array();
for( var key in phoneBook )
    array_values.push( phoneBook[key] );
store.loadRawData( array_values );
```